# AChartEngine in java eclipse

Tags: android

hello everyone i have a  problem in setting the color of my graph...
how will i set the color..please help me thanks..

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    rendrer.setColor(Color, WHITE);//There is an error here

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);


    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, 
                                                          mRenderer, "Line Graph Title");
    return intent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give rgb values as below

```
renderer.setColor(Color.rgb(248, 248, 255));
```